# variables in filename

Tags: string-manipulation

I have some scv files, they are named based on the testing condition from the simulation runs, basically from blk50_25 to blk300_150, the first number after "blk" was ranged from 50 to 300 incremented by 10, and 2nd number after "_" was ranged from 25 to 150 incremented by 5. (i.e first file blk50_25, 2nd file blk60_30, 3rd file blk70_35, etc.) I'm trying to write a loop to call all the files and do an x-y plot of each, here's what I have done

```
data = Import["/Users/Desktop/ConvTestOP/blk50_25.csv", "CSV"]
MD = Table[{data[[j, 1]], data[[j, 2]]}, {j, 1, Length[data]}];
Reverse /@ MD
ListPlot[MD[[All, {2, 1}]]]
```

I'm not sure how to put variables in the filename, much appreciated if anyone can give me a hint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For old versions:

```
Table[ToString[StringForm["/Users/Desktop/ConvTestOP/blk`1`_`2`.csv",
                          10 k + 50, 5 k + 25]], {k, 0, 25}]
```

For new versions:

```
Table[StringTemplate["/Users/Desktop/ConvTestOP/blk`i`_`j`.csv"] @
      <|"i" -> 10 k + 50, "j" -> 5 k + 25|>, {k, 0, 25}]
```

Both generate a list of the filenames following your system; modify the `Table[]` as needed (e.g. incorporating `Import[]` and `ListPlot[]`).

Comment: Thanks for the speed response, when I name the data, is there a way to do something like `data_i_j = Import["/Users/Desktop/ConvTestOP/blki_j.csv", "CSV"]` where `i` and `j` are based on your code above?

Comment: @Gavy, you can do something like `Table[data[10 k + 50, 5 k + 25] = (* stuff *)]` for that, and then refer to `data[50, 25]`, `data[60, 30]`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, you can grab all the file names of the appropriate type and read them in. This means you don't need to know the exact names of the files in advance.

```
allfiles = FileNames["*", "/Users/Desktop/ConvTestOP/"];
allData = Import[#] & /@ allfiles;
```

then build your plots directly from allData.